# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i get this error When i try to render the list to the view from a backend service,
am able to get the response data and log it to the console but it wont render on the view.

> enter code here

```html
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentsService } from '../services/students.service';
import { Student } from '../interfaces/Student';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css'],
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() student: Student;
  students: Student[];
  constructor(private studentService: StudentsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentService.getStudents().subscribe((students) => {
      (data) => {
        this.students = data.json();
        Array.of(this.students);
      };
      console.log(students);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
export interface Student {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  date_of_birth: Date;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <ul *ngFor="let student of students">
    <li>{{student.first_name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   (data) => {
        this.students = data.json();
        Array.of(this.students);
      };
```

it shouldn't be a function. change it to something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentsService } from '../services/students.service';
import { Student } from '../interfaces/Student';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css'],
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() student: Student;
  students: Student[];
  constructor(private studentService: StudentsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
          this.studentService.getStudents().subscribe((students) => {
      this.students = students; // students is response from server. if it is not Student[] you should map it to correct type.
    });
  }
}
```